# Multiple Bindings from homepage

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, reference, viewmodel

My homepage passes its viewmodel as follows

```
public HomePage(myHomePageViewModel hpViewModel) //
        {
            var form = new myHomePageViewModel();
            this.BindingContext = form;
            form.UserData();
            form.ExecuteLoadItemsCommand();
        }
        
        public myHomePageViewModel ViewModel 
        {
            get { return (myHomePageViewModel)BindingContext; }
            set { BindingContext = value; }
        }
```

This works fine, however I cant reference my xamarin ListView tap gesture. Is there any way I can continue to bind to my view model as well as reference my listview image tap gestures?

Comment: if your question is about binding your listview and your VM, it would help a great deal if you posted the relevant code.  The code you have posted doesn't seem to have very little do with the actual question you have asked.

Comment: Hi Jason, the question is not focused on my view model, it is how I can still reference my listview image gesture from code behind as it is not available since I have already binded to the view model.

Comment: Bind the tap gesture to the [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap#using-icommand) in the view model.